# What does the phrase "happen to be" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxEsWPzg6uc) while in 1:19 Sec I have heard so:

> "I **happen to be** pro-life"

What does it mean? I have tried to find it on some dictionaries (Cambridge, Oxford and Merriam Webster) and I didn't find the meaning.

Comment: Obviously, being pro-life (anti-abortion) is a moral choice. It is no accident. The speaker is trying to de-emphasise the fact by suggesting that it is a matter of chance and therefore not something for anyone else to make an issue of. It is a pretence that he hopes others will go along with.

Answer (score 6):

It's basically a less emphatic way of saying that someone *is* something. In other words:

> He happens to be the sheriff in this town.

is more or less the same as:

> He is the sheriff in this town.

Or:

> She happens to be the dean of the college.

is pretty much the same as:

> She is the dean of the college.

However, using *happens to be* instead of *is* implies some sort of coincidence or irony or causation. I wouldn't use *happens to be* instead of *is* unless the context called for it. For example:

> "Wow, that guy just drove by fast!"
>   *Well, he happens to be the town sheriff. I don't think he's worried about getting a speeding ticket.*

Or:

> "I see her taking the elevator up to the top floor every morning."
>   *Well, she happens to be the dean of the college. Her office is up there*.

Comment: Thank you. Is this phrase always in present simple tense form, and then "she happened to be the dean of the college" is not correct?

Comment: @Industrious - No, it can be used with any tense.

Answer (score 3):

I think JR’s explanation is excellent.  I would just add that “to happen to be” is also used to convey seemingly tangential information, that is often, in reality, very important.  As JR said, it’s a way of being less emphatic than saying “is”, as if the fact is just an interesting coincidence.  However, IMO, it’s not a coincidence.  The writer is strongly implying that what they “happen to be” is influencing what they are writing.

For example:

“An airline pilot would never try to land at that speed.”

Versus

“I happen to be a pilot, and an airline pilot would never try to land at that speed.”

Versus

“I am a pilot, and an airline pilot would never try to land at that speed.”

I think the writer saying “I happen to be a pilot” is trying to imply that saying she is a pilot adds weight to her opinion, but wants to suggest that the fact she is a pilot is tangential/coincidental to her opinion.  I think writing “I am a pilot” suggests that the rest of her statement isn’t an opinion, but a fact.